# Storing session data in asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm using `Session` in my application to store some data like user name(to write hello,...) and so on. Also, I'm using `FormsAuthentication` to authenticate user, so controllers have code like this:

```
protected void SetAuthCookie(int userId)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId.ToString(), true);
        User user = Repositories.UserRepository.GetUserById(userId);

        Session["name"] = user.Name;
        Session["email"] = user.Email;
        Session["balance"] = user.TotalBalance + " / " + user.ActiveBalance;
        Session["isConfirmed"] = user.IsConfirmed;
        Session["phone"] = user.Phone;
    }
```

So, when I restart application after some code changes session data is destroyed, but user is still authenticated, so I have very bad situation and I want to fix it. On the one hand, I can create code somewhere, that will check if session data is ok and refresh it otherwise. On the other hand, may I miss some technique of storing this data in the right way?

What is the best solution in this situation?

---

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: cookies persist across sessions. what's the problem here? when you detect the cookie, set the session values.

Comment: also, using the session isn't recommended with MVC. MVC is meant to be as stateless as possible, and relying on the session would break that.

Comment: Sometimes, user is authenticated, but session data doesn't exist anymore. It happens, when I restart application after code changes and I'm afraid of this situation in other case

Comment: Okey, and how to store data like this in right way so?)

Comment: Check timeout attribute value of
<authentication mode="Forms"> and <sessionState>

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

Comment: If the session is `inProc`, it would be destroyed when you recycle the applicationpool, which happens when you either update the web.config or rebuild (deploying new assemblies).

Comment: @RollerCosta it is 2880, but it just happens after restart)

Comment: @scheien so, I just should ignore it and understand, that it may happen only when something is rebuilt?

Comment: I would recommend you to add your web.config entries of SessionState and   authentication model, in the question itself.

Comment: @lenden: It will also happen when the applicationpool recycles, which is every 20mins of inactivity (if you haven't changed any default settings).

Comment: The problem is in the code, not with the way authentication works. Don't try to "fix" what isn't broken. Your code assumes that only non-authenticated users will ever visit your site which is obviously wrong. You can just check the Session object and refill it if you find it's empty.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you, I've opened my eyes, it was so obvious..

Comment: Can anybody advise, where to put code, that will check the Session object and refill it? I mean globally, put it to every controller, global asax, anything else maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem solved it like this in the **global.asax.cs** file: It will force a logout if session is empty and the request is authenticated. (take one of your session values that always sholud be set to check for null)

```
    protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ForceLogoutIfSessionExpired();
    }

    private void ForceLogoutIfSessionExpired()
    {
        if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState)
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["name"] == null)
                {
                    AuthenticationHandler.SignOut(Response);
                    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for idea of Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute, I think it's what I need. But I'd prefer to refill Session data if it's empty, but not to signout user, it is also normal plan, isn't it?